# What is better in terms of performance in T-SQL? Inner + Sub-Queries or Inner + Virtual Table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, subquery, inner-join, virtual-table

I have a doubt in terms of performance.

What is better?

1. Multiple nested Inner Joins + SubQueries with a specific WHERE clause (the table has indexes).
2. Creating a virtual table with row data and relating it with Inner Joins?

Comment: Try both queries and check the execution plan...

Comment: Can you show us SQL code for both cases, and maybe some data as well?  Your question is kind of not specific.

Comment: You can always run both, measure, find out - come back and tell us - real evidence tends to be better than the thought experiment.

Comment: Ok, I will do both Queries and I will tell you the times!

Comment: Worth reading Eric Lippert's [Which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) too. Although there a slight .NET slant at the start, most of it is broadly applicable across languages/technologies.

Comment: My current generic comment re "better"/"best" etc: There's no such thing as "better"/"best" in engineering unless *you* define it. Also unfortunately all reasonable practical definitions require a ridiculous amount of experience with a ridiculous number of factors that interact with chaotic sensitivity to details. Make straightforward designs. When you demonstrate via measurement that a design and all alternatives you can think of have problems (whatever that means at the time), then ask a very specific question. Which should also define "better"/"best". https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461